# Getting "No such interface supported" when connecting to a remote Performance Monitor

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-access, performance-monitoring

I have 6 machines:

- 2 x Windows 7 32-bit (W71, W72)
- 4 x Windows 2008 R2 64-bit (W2k81, W2k82, W2k83, W2k84)

I want to access the W2k8 machines' performance monitors remotely from the W7 machines.

It is only a testing environment, so:

- the machines are not in a domain, but they all belong to the same workgroup
- they all have an account with the same name that is member of groups:

  - Administrators
  - Performance Log Users
  - Performance Monitor Users
- all firewalls have been turned off
- the following services are confirmed to be running on the W2k8 machines:

  - Remote Registry
  - Performance Logs & Alerts
  - Performance Counter DLL Host
  - Remote Procedure Call (RPC)

I can connect remotely from W71 to W72's performance monitor and vice-versa. However, no computer can connect remotely to any of the W2k8 computers' performance monitors.

*EDIT:* I forgot to mention that the error I get when connecting to a performance monitor remotely is:

> When attempting to connect to the remote computer the following system error occurred:
>
> No such interface supported

*FURTHER EDIT:* I am trying to access the remote computer by right-clicking on *Performance* > *Connect to another computer...* and providing the IP address of the remote computer:

[image: Connecting to a remote computer]

I am open to any suggestions.

*POSSIBLE SOLUTION:* Apparently, I can access the remote computers' counters not as described above, but by specifying a remote computer's IP address (or name) when adding a new counter:

[image: Adding counters from a remote computer]

Answer (score 3):

This is a firewall issue and a permissions issue. I had the same problem trying to monitor a slow server remotely from a workstation.  Solution is:

1. Enable Performance Logging on the inbound firewall rules of the remote computer.
2. Add yourself to the Performance Log Users group on the remote computer.
3. Add yourself to the Event Log Readers group on the remote computer.

Comment: The inbound rules are called "Peformance Logs and Alerts (DCOM-In)" and "Performance Logs and Alerts (TCP-In)".

Answer (score 0):

The reason why perfmon.exe do not want to connect to the remote server is, it wants to connect to the Perf Monitor **and** the Perf Logs (Data collections).

So you have to add the user account to **also the Log User group** and of course to the Monitor Users.

[image]